# Checking if flag is set as well as storing a default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I know that you can check if a flag is set using something like this,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--flag', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.flag:
   foo()
```

but is there a way to check if the flag is set and have a default value associated with the variable? Like this,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--flag', action='store_true', type=str, default='text')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.flag:
    foo(args.flag) # Need the default text now
```

From my understanding, python will store True/False based on whether the flag was input or not. Therefore, would it be possible to establish two separate destinations? One to hold the action and want to have the value? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: There are workarounds that I could use, but they are ugly, just looking for a simple solution if one exists.

Comment: The default `'store'` plus a `nargs='?'` is handy.  It allows for a 3 way set - default, const, and user-value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `action="store_const"` with `const` keyword argument instead of `default`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--flag', action="store_const", const="default text")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.flag:
        print(args.flag) # Need the default text now
```